# Replicating the map() from pandas.Series in Julia

Tags: dictionary, julia

I took `Base.map` from the julia documentation to replicate the functionality of the `map()` from pandas.Series.map in Julia.
I have tried to replicate the syntax in Julia but having some trouble in replicating the functionality.

#Python reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html

#julia code:

```
s = ["cat", "dog", NaN, "rabbit"]
map!(x->x, s, ["dog"])
```

The above mentioned code snippet does replace the item but not sure how I can run it in iteration such that it checks the every location and if there is no replacement described it returns NaN.

Please suggest what will be the correct methodology to replicate the `Pandas.Series.map()` in Julia.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you please specify what output you want here? I'm not familiar with Pandas. What is happening in your current code example is that it takes `"dog"`, replaces it with `"dog"`, and then puts it into the first element of the vector `s` (overwriting the entry `"cat"`). Then it stops and doesn't iterate any further.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any built-in functionality that does this, but you can write your own quite straightforwardly. What you want is something similar to `replace` with some tweaks:

```
function myreplace!(a::AbstractArray, old_new::Pair...; fallback=NaN)
    for i in eachindex(a)
        val = a[i]
        usefallback = true
        for on in old_new
            if val == first(on)
                a[i] = last(on)
                usefallback = false
                break
            end
        end
        if usefallback
            a[i] = fallback
        end
    end
    return a
end

# Non-inplace version
myreplace(a, args...; kwargs...) = myreplace!(copy(a), args...; kwargs...)
```

Example:

```
jl> s = ["cat", "dog", NaN, "rabbit"];

jl> myreplace(s, "cat"=>"kitten", "dog"=>"puppy"; fallback=NaN)
4-element Vector{Any}:
    "kitten"
    "puppy"
 NaN
 NaN
```

Comment: thanks for this amazing snippet, highly appreciate it !!!

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that a transformation function is required, so the following will work:

```
julia> s = ["cat", "dog", NaN, "rabbit"]
4-element Vector{Any}:
    "cat"
    "dog"
 NaN
    "rabbit"

julia> map!(x -> x === NaN ? "dog" : x, s, s)
4-element Vector{Any}:
 "cat"
 "dog"
 "dog"
 "rabbit"
```

Note though that in Julia `NaN` is not used for represent missing values, but rather `missing`, so normally you would write:

```
julia> s = ["cat", "dog", missing, "rabbit"]
4-element Vector{Union{Missing, String}}:
 "cat"
 "dog"
 missing
 "rabbit"

julia> map!(x -> coalesce(x, "dog"), s, s)
4-element Vector{Union{Missing, String}}:
 "cat"
 "dog"
 "dog"
 "rabbit"
```

It would be even easier if you did not want an in-place operation as then you can just write:

```
julia> s = ["cat", "dog", missing, "rabbit"]
4-element Vector{Union{Missing, String}}:
 "cat"
 "dog"
 missing
 "rabbit"

julia> coalesce.(s, "dog")
4-element Vector{String}:
 "cat"
 "dog"
 "dog"
 "rabbit"
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I am looking for something presented by @ DNF in the above comment. Yeah agree on `NaN` and `missing`, it is fine if it returns missing as long as I can replicate the operation.

Comment: Then you have `replace!` function from Julia Base and `recode!` function n CategoricalArrays.jl. Maybe you would find them useful.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, highly appreciate your help. I will try to have a look at these functions, will update on my findings.

Answer (score 1):

AFAICT [`recode`](https://categoricalarrays.juliadata.org/stable/apiindex/#CategoricalArrays.recode) in CategoricalArrays was precisely designed to do this. Though in Julia you should use `missing` rather than `NaN` to represent missing values.

```
julia> s = ["cat", "dog", missing, "rabbit"]
4-element Vector{Union{Missing, String}}:
 "cat"
 "dog"
 missing
 "rabbit"

julia> recode(s, "cat"=>"kitten", "dog"=>"puppy")
4-element Vector{Union{Missing, String}}:
 "kitten"
 "puppy"
 missing
 "rabbit"

# With a fallback to missing for values that are not listed
julia> recode(s, missing, "cat"=>"kitten", "dog"=>"puppy")
4-element Vector{Union{Missing, String}}:
 "kitten"
 "puppy"
 missing
 missing

# Also works in-place with recode!
julia> recode!(s, "cat"=>"kitten", "dog"=>"puppy");

julia> s
4-element Vector{Union{Missing, String}}:
 "kitten"
 "puppy"
 missing
 "rabbit"
```